# javascript changing Object.prototype not work

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototype-programming

It is just for experiment. The following code seems not able to change Object.prototype to null.

```
Object.prototype = null;
var o = new Object();
```

Is it just because it is 'Object' or built-in types? I think we can change it for user-defined types. Sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: Is that a bad thing ? But what's the question ? Why it's read only ?

Comment: Just curious why. Where are my new value? Just quietly ignored. Give an exception or error when you think that's not right.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.1 because the spec says so. that is why.

Comment: rlemon, thanks for pointing out the place inside the spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From MSDN**
Some more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5s9ycex(v=vs.94).aspx

> All intrinsic JavaScript objects have a prototype property that is
>   read-only. Properties and methods may be added to the prototype, but
>   the object may not be assigned a different prototype. However,
>   user-defined objects may be assigned a new prototype. The method and
>   property lists for each intrinsic object in this language reference
>   indicate which ones are part of the object's prototype, and which are
>   not.

**From the specification**
Some more info here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.1

> 15.2.3.1 Object.prototype
>
> The initial value of Object.prototype is the standard built-in Object
>   prototype object (15.2.4).
>
> This property has the attributes {[[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]:
>   false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

Answer (score 0):

[15.2.3.1 Object.prototype](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.1) specifies that:

> This property has the attributes {[[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]:
>   false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

and [8.6.1 Property Attributes](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.1) has this to say about `[[Writable]]`:

> If false, attempts by ECMAScript code to change the property’s
>   [[Value]] attribute using [[Put]] will not succeed.